# Generate 4-digit number without random class

Tags: java

I am trying to generate a random 4-digit number using the Java Math.random method. The number must always be 4 digits, i.e., allow for results such as `0001`, or `0023`, or `0123` to be possible. However, the traditional `Math.random` method formula below only allows numbers less than 1000 to be 1, 23, or 123.

```
int i = (int)(Math.random()*10000);
```

Is there a way to do this using math.random and/or loops?
Thank you, in advance, for any suggestions.

I tried researching how to ensure the 4-digit number always has 4 digits, but all results seem to suggest using Random class, or min/max. 
I DO NOT want to use this random class or max/min code as I have not yet studied it yet.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem here is not the `Random` class, but to pad the numbers which don't have 4 digits. Therefore you have to use a String instead of an int. You can pad the number by using `String.format()`:

```
Random random = new Random();
int number = random.nextInt(10000);
String result = String.format("%04d", number);
```

This will ensure that your `result` String has always 4 digits.